# Trying to write a function to determine if a complex object's deeply nested sub array has values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a function to check a deeply nested sub array inside of a complex object to return true if it has values or false if it is empty but I'm not sure how to do this.

The section I'm trying to check is contacts inside each contactGroups section which is where I'm running into issues because the array is nested 4 levels down like `object > array of objects > object > contacts array` and I'm not sure how to map or iterate at that level.

This is my first pass at a function which is more pseudo code at this point:

```
  const hasContacts = (contacts: {}) => {
    if(contacts.contactGroups.length === 0 
       || contacts.contactGroups.map((contact) => contactGroups.contacts === undefined 
       || contacts.contactGroups.map((contact) => contactGroups.contacts.length === 0 ){
      return false
    }

    return contacts
  }
```

The data structure looks like this:

```
const mockContacts = {
  count: 1,
  contactGroups: [
    {
      contactGroup: "Family",
      count: 2,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: "Uncle",
          fullName: "BENJAMIN BILLIARDS",
          lastName: "BILLIARDS",
          firstName: "BENJAMIN",
          email: "shark@billiards.com",
        },
        {
          member: "Aunt",
          fullName: "DENISE NICE",
          lastName: "NICE",
          firstName: "DENISE",
          email: "floral@flowers.com",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      contactGroup: "Friends",
      count: 2,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: "School Friend",
          fullName: "DERRICK SMITH",
          lastName: "SMITH",
          firstName: "DERRICK",
          email: "smith978@gmail.com",
        },
        {
          member: "Work Friend",
          fullName: "TARA SKY",
          lastName: "SKY",
          firstName: "TARA",
          email: "uptown94@gmail.com",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: `!!contacts.contactGroups` made into a boolean so seems simpler way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return boolean if there are any contacts then you can do the following:

```js
const hasContacts = ({ contactGroups = [] } = []) =>
  contactGroups.some(
    ({ contacts = [] } = {}) => contacts.length
  );

console.log('pass undefined', hasContacts());
console.log('pass empty object', hasContacts({}));
console.log(
  'pass empty contact group',
  hasContacts({ contactGroups: [] })
);
console.log(
  'pass empty contacts',
  hasContacts({ contactGroups: [{ contacts: [] }] })
);
console.log(
  'pass contacts',
  hasContacts({ contactGroups: [{ contacts: [1] }] })
);
console.log(
  'pass some contacts',
  hasContacts({
    contactGroups: [{ contacts: [] }, { contacts: [1] }],
  })
);

const mockContacts = {
  count: 1,
  contactGroups: [
    {
      contactGroup: 'Family',
      count: 2,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: 'Uncle',
          fullName: 'BENJAMIN BILLIARDS',
          lastName: 'BILLIARDS',
          firstName: 'BENJAMIN',
          email: 'shark@billiards.com',
        },
        {
          member: 'Aunt',
          fullName: 'DENISE NICE',
          lastName: 'NICE',
          firstName: 'DENISE',
          email: 'floral@flowers.com',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      contactGroup: 'Friends',
      count: 2,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: 'School Friend',
          fullName: 'DERRICK SMITH',
          lastName: 'SMITH',
          firstName: 'DERRICK',
          email: 'smith978@gmail.com',
        },
        {
          member: 'Work Friend',
          fullName: 'TARA SKY',
          lastName: 'SKY',
          firstName: 'TARA',
          email: 'uptown94@gmail.com',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
console.log(
  'mock contacts:',
  hasContacts(mockContacts)
);
```

Comment: I wrote out the function like ```const hasContacts = ({ contactGroups = [] } = []) => (contactGroups.some(({ contacts = [] } = {}) => contacts.length))``` and when I go to console log it out like ```console.log('has contacts: ', hasContacts(mockContacts));``` I'm getting a type error saying ```Type 'MockContacts' is missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the whole mockContacts object in and determine if any of the contact group objects have contacts inside the contacts array?

Comment: @Josh I pass mockContacts from your question to hasContacts and get no error (see updated question). `Is there a way to pass the whole mockContacts object in and determine if any of the contact group objects have contacts inside the contacts array?` That is what the function is currently doing. If that is not what you want then please update your question with expected input and output examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the nested contactGroup contacts cannot also have more nesting then this solution should work for you. I was unclear on how you wanted to handle each nested group so I returned an array that will tell you if each nested group does or does not have contacts.

```js
const mockContacts = {
    count: 1,
    contactGroups: [
        {
            contactGroup: "Family",
            count: 2,
            contacts: [
                {
                    member: "Uncle",
                    fullName: "BENJAMIN BILLIARDS",
                    lastName: "BILLIARDS",
                    firstName: "BENJAMIN",
                    email: "shark@billiards.com",
                },
                {
                    member: "Aunt",
                    fullName: "DENISE NICE",
                    lastName: "NICE",
                    firstName: "DENISE",
                    email: "floral@flowers.com",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            contactGroup: "Friends",
            count: 2,
            contacts: [
                {
                    member: "School Friend",
                    fullName: "DERRICK SMITH",
                    lastName: "SMITH",
                    firstName: "DERRICK",
                    email: "smith978@gmail.com",
                },
                {
                    member: "Work Friend",
                    fullName: "TARA SKY",
                    lastName: "SKY",
                    firstName: "TARA",
                    email: "uptown94@gmail.com",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

const hasContacts = (contacts) => {
    // if contacts is not undefined, then check contactGroup
    if (contacts && Array.isArray(contacts.contactGroups)) {
        // we can have more than one contact group so need to check each
        return contacts.contactGroups.map(row=>Array.isArray(row.contacts) && row.contacts.length > 0)
    }
}

console.log(hasContacts(mockContacts))
```